# Sublime Text C++ : user input with cin

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, cin

Sorry for the question that may seems very obvious for most of you, I'm new into programming, I'm learning C++ at school and we're using Codeblocks on Windows, at home I'm using Sublime with my Mac and I want to know if it's possible to get user input with Sublime by using "cin", just like I do with Codeblocks.

Let me give you an example, it's gonna be easier to understand. If I do :

```
cout << "enter month :" ; 
cin >> month ;
```

When running the program, "enter month" appear but I can't type anything after that.

Same problem as here actually, but no answer :
[Get Sublime Text 2 to accept user input in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996947/get-sublime-text-2-to-accept-user-input-in-c)

Also a post here about the same kind of problem :
https://superuser.com/questions/871916/how-to-make-sublime-text-3-take-user-input

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

It is the same language. ofcourse you can

Comment: The thing is when I run my program in Sublime, I just don't get the user input, can't type anything.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? I dont know what you mean.

Comment: I edited my post with more infos, I think it's easier to understand now !

Comment: Just link the whole source file

Comment: It is pretty much the same kind of thing as here : https://superuser.com/questions/871916/how-to-make-sublime-text-3-take-user-input